# ReactJS: What is the best way of creating bi-directional relationship between an array in the state, and its data-bound inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

Of course my title ain't clear enough. Let me explain exactly what i mean:

Recently i did a project with AngulaJS(1), and i was amazed how easy it is to create a relationship between the "scope"(which is more or less the equivalent of the "state" in a React component), and the view. For example: let's say i get some initial JSON, which holds data about various people, and i create a key for it, on the $scope object. It would look like that:

```
$scope.people= [
        { 
            name: 'John', age: 23
        },
        {
            name: 'Sarah',
            age: 45
        },
        {
            name: 'Michael',
            age: 42
        },
        {
            name: 'Samantha',
            age: 23
        },
        {
            name: 'Joe',
            age: 12
        },
    ]
```

Then, the HTML, will dynamically output it using ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
    <label for="">name: </label>
    <input ng-model="person.name" type="text">
    <label for="">age: </label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="person.age">
    <hr>
</div>
```

I now have input fields for each person, and i can easily overwrite the initial data(this would be useful in some "edit my account" form, or something similar.) I do not need any callbacks. I do not need to create new objects. Each iteration in the ng-repeat has a reference to the relevant element in the array. Easy as pie.

Now, to the issue: I wanted to create the same functionality using React, which doesn't have two-way data binding of course, and has to use setState, to return a new state object.

This is what i've done:

```
onChange = (e,prop,index)=>{
    const newVal = e.target.value;
    this.setState((prev)=>{
      const newArr = [...prev.people]
      newArr[index][prop]=newVal     
      return{
        people:newArr
      }
    })
  }
```

And then the JSX:

```
<div>
        {
          this.state.people.map((person, index) => {
            return (
              <div>
                <label htmlFor="name"></label>
                <input onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, 'name', index) }} type="text" value={this.state.people[index].name} />
                <label htmlFor="age"></label>
                <input onChange={(e) => { this.onChange(e, 'age', index) }} type="text" value={this.state.people[index].age} />
                <hr />
                <br />
              </div>
            )
          })
        }
      </div>
```

Notice how i had(did i..?) to pass the index and the property name to the callback function.

This does the job, but seems to me like an over-complicated way, to achieve something that is seemingly trivial and simple. After all, look how easy it was it AngularJS(1).

The question: what is the easiest approach to this issue in React? I'm pretty sure there is a less convoluted way to do this.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you're trying to achieve something that React wasn't designed for. It's not built for 2 way data binding. If that's what you're after look at Angular that you've already found or something else like KnockoutJS. Find the best tool for the job - don't get stuck in a single framework and try to force it to do everything.

Comment: Ian, thank you for your reply. Yes, of course i could use a different technology, but being that i'm not a freelancer, i need to use the framework, that some job requires. Besides, React has also some advantages over AngualrJS(many advantages...)